# LiquidSoap - modifying stream meta description to match schedule

Tags: streaming, icecast, liquidsoap

So using LiquidSoap for driving my radio station.  I have 3 playlists defined and a schedule to switch between them:

```
pl1 = nrj(playlist("/var/www/html/radiojuno.com/playlists/pl1.m3u"))
pl2 = nrj(playlist("/var/www/html/radiojuno.com/playlists/pl2.m3u"))
pl3 = nrj(playlist("/var/www/html/radiojuno.com/playlists/pl3.m3u"))

radio = switch([ ({22h-7h}, pl1), ({7h-19h}, pl2), ({19h-22h}, pl3) ])

output.icecast(
    %mp3,
    host = "localhost",
    port = 8000,
    password = "xxxx",
    mount = "mymount",
    genre="Electronic",
    description="**Current show description**",
    url="http://example.com",
    radio
)
```

I'd like to modify the description of the stream according to the current schedule.

But I can't work out how this can be achieved with LiquidSoap. I've been staring at https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.4.2/metadata.html for hours!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks good to me. Do you find any errors in the log file? (see [here](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.4.2/settings.html#log-configuration-1) how to log)

Comment: That configuration 'works' so I wouldn't expect any errors.  I'm trying to figure out how to modify the description of the stream ("**Current show description**") according to the schedule, so I can inform my listeners which 'show' they're listening to...

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. So you want to change the description depending on the playlist that is running?

Comment: @naitsirch - yes - exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pity, but Icecast does not support updating the server information like *name* or *description* during a source connection.

The reason for this is that those information are sent via HTTP headers when the source client connects to the server. For more information have a look [at the protocol](https://gist.github.com/ePirat/adc3b8ba00d85b7e3870).

Here are the sources backing up my answer:

- https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap/issues/710
- http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/icecast/2010-December/011774.html
- http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/icecast/2005-April/009022.html